# Else statement not working even if condition suffices

Tags: python, sqlite, python-3.4

```
usrIngredient = input("\nEnter an ingredient that you would like to make a drink with: \n\n")


query = c.execute("SELECT DRDESC FROM Drinks WHERE DRDRID IN"
                  "(SELECT DTDRID FROM Detail WHERE INGID "
                  "=(SELECT INGID FROM Ingredients WHERE INDESC LIKE ?))", (usrIngredient,))

resultset = c.fetchall()

for result in resultset:
    if resultset != None:
        result = ' '.join(result)
        print(result)
    else:
        print("Sorry, there are no drinks with that ingredient")
```

I am executing a SQL query that fetches all of the drinks from my database that have the ingredient that the user enters.  If there is no drink that has the ingredient that the user entered... it should print out the last line of code.  Instead it prints a blank line.

Comment: Basically everything you're trying to do will fail with a `NoneType`: `for result in None` is a `TypeError`, for example. `result` and `resultset` are not `None`. `if resultset:` is probably what you need, as an empty resultset is `[]`, not `None`.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no result, `resultset` is an empty list and the for-loop is never entered. You may want try this:

```
resultset = c.fetchall()
if not resultset:
    print("Sorry, there are no drinks with that ingredient")
else:
    for drdesc, in resultset:
        print(drdesc)
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically everything you're trying to do will fail with a `NoneType`: `for result in None` is a `TypeError`, for example. `result` and `resultset` are not `None`.

`if resultset:` is probably what you need, as an empty resultset from [cur.fetchall()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchall) is `[]`, not `None`.

Answer (score 0):

When the result set is empty, the `for` loop body is never executed (because there is nothing that could be assigned to `result`). So the `if` in the body never gets executed.

To check whether a `for` loop did not run at all, you'd have to put the `else` clause on the `for` itself:

```
for result in resultset:
    ...
else:
    print("Sorry, there are no drinks with that ingredient")
```

And `result` gets assigned a new value every time the `for` loop iterates, so you cannot use it to collect the overall result; you'd have to use a different variable. And the items in `resultset` are rows, i.e., they are tuples containing the column values (even if there is a single column); you have to use something like `x[0]` to extract the value from the tuple. And `join` expects a list. And you can iterate directly over the cursor instead of reading all results into memory first:

```
c.execute("...")
result = ' '.join([row[0] for row in c])
if result != '':
    print(result)
else:
    print("Sorry, there are no drinks with that ingredient")
```